# How to align floated logo in horizontal navbar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to horizontally align my logo with the list but the logo sticks up, I could use a margin to move it down but will that be the right way to align it or is there a better way.[image]

```
<div class="navigation-bar">
    <div class="nav-wrap">
      <div class="nav-bar">
        <div class="logo">
          <img class="" alt="Logo" src="../assets/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav-list">
          <ul>
            <li>I didn’t get my tickets</li>
            <li><a>CREATE YOUR OWN EVENT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
.nav-wrap {
  clear: both;
  overflow: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}
.nav-bar {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  line-height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
}
.nav-list {
  float: right;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: raleway;
}

img {
  height: 32px;
  width: 172px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

This is my code, how do I properly fix this?

Comment: you wanna align horizontally or vertically? please provide a reproducible example with what you want to achieve

Comment: I don't understand your issue. What do you want to archive?

Comment: If you do a little bit a research, there are already many many answered questions on this site and many others for your topic.  Search "horizontal alignment of image with div" or "horizontal alignment of divs" or "horizontal alignment of elements" etc. You will find several methods of achieving this.  Pick whichever suits your particular needs the best.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a JSFiddle to assist you with visualising this response: https://jsfiddle.net/wn8avcbt/

In your **.nav-bar** class you will need to ensure that it is of display:flex and uses align content and align items with centering. **align-items** is the specific CSS element you are looking for: I would not make the image absolute and instead would let it follow the flex of its parent.

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

If you have any questions, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

In the `.logo` styling, say `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;`. If you don't understand it, go to https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp. I hope that helped!

Comment: Sorry @UnReal G. I saw your answer after I posted mine. Yours works too.